# Saving and applying a keras model to unseen data

Tags: python-3.x, keras, multiclass-classification

I am building a model for my multiclass text classification problem which looks like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
for units in [128, 128, 64 , 32]: # automatically adding layers through a for loop
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(18, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

# Optimiser Function
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_data_f,
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=test_data_f,
                    verbose=1,
                    class_weight=class_weights
       )
```

Once the build is done, I would like to do the following:

1. Save the model
2. Load the model and apply it to an unseen text (For Example: the column on which I would want to apply this model is df['Unseen_Text]

how can I achieve this?

Comment: How is the title related to your questions?

Comment: My bad! apologies. updated the title now.

Comment: To answer your questions: [saving](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/) and [predicting](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#predict-method).

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your main issue. Is it just "Saving and applying a keras model to unseen data", or is there any specific problem in your code I missed?

Regardless, there are a few points worth mentioning after looking at your code:

1. you have `from_logits=True` while for the last layer `activation='softmax'`.
2. `metrics=['accuracy']` may not be a great choice for your case. You may want to consider `CategoricalAccuracy` and/or `AUC`.
3. I didn't see the definition of `class_weights`, but I assume you define it in your main code.

Comment: The main issue was just saving and loading the model again only. But as you have pointed a couple of important things, I already made some changes to my model yesterday but got into another problem of lower prc score. If you can have a look at my other question and share your suggestion around that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977617/lstm-model-is-producing-really-bad-results-for-multiclass-text-classification-fo